# Simplifying LINQ subquery with alias

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, orm

```
var q1 = (
    from routes in ctx.RMBUSROUTEDTLs
    where new { routes.ROUTENO, routes.SEQ } == new { ROUTENO = routeNO, SEQ = seq }
    select routes
);

var routeDetail = (
    from route in q1
    where route.ROUTEVER == q1.Select(x => x.ROUTEVER).Max()
    select route
).Single();
```

Currently I am doing subquery like this. Subquery `q1` was taken out because I need to reference to its result from the outer query. However, all we know is that SQL can use alias to achieve that and we do not need to take out the subquery. May I know if there a way to perform such syntax? An example is shown below.

```
var routeDetail = (
    from route in (
        from routes in ctx.RMBUSROUTEDTLs
        where new { routes.ROUTENO, routes.SEQ } == new { ROUTENO = routeNO, SEQ = seq }
        select routes
    ) q1
    where route.ROUTEVER == q1.Select(x => x.ROUTEVER).Max()
    select route
).Single();
```

Comment: Even the first scenario where `q1` is initialized, you will notice that query won't be executed until `Single()` method is not invoked, You can run the profile and capture the SQL and you will notice that EF would be optimizing the query by it's own.

Comment: @user1672994 Thanks for your explanation, I know this fact, so I am not talking about the performance. I just want to know how can I embed q1 inside instead of taking it out as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this?

```
var routeDetail = (
  from route in ctx.RMBUSROUTEDTLs
  where new { route.ROUTENO, route.SEQ } == new { ROUTENO = routeNO, SEQ = seq }
  where route.ROUTEVER == q1.Select(x => x.ROUTEVER).Max()
  select route
).Single();
```

You can even combine both `where` clauses, if you want.